# swiper slider in framework7 V1 creating blank page after and before first and last image

Tags: cordova, html-framework-7

when i am using swiper slider from framework 7 in my cordova app having static images. the slider works perfect, but when i am getting the images dynamically from web service it is creating blank pages before 1st image and after last image , the slider dont stop, here is my sample code

when the image is static:----

```
<div data-space-between="50" class="swiper-container swiper-init" >
     <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <div class="swiper-wrapper" id="plot_img">

      <div class="swiper-slide" ><img src="images/slider1.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slide_text">
          <h4>some head1</h4>
          <p>sometext1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="images/slider1.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="slide_text">
            <h4>some head2</h4>
            <p>some text2</p>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

when i am getting the image dynamically here is the html, i am trying to plot image in id="plot_img"

```
<div data-space-between="50" class="swiper-container swiper-init" >
     <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <div class="swiper-wrapper" id="plot_img">
     </div>
</div>
```

here is the ajax code

```
json.response.forEach(function(obj,val){
      imghtml += '<div class="swiper-slide"><img 
    src="'+json.url_to_append+''+obj.fields.featured_image+'" alt="">
    <div 
    class="slide_text"><h4>'+obj.fields.banner_name+'</h4>
    <p>'+obj.fields.banner_description+'</p></div></div>';
});

$$('#plot_img').html(imghtml)
```

Comment: can you add output obj variable

Comment: 0: {model: "banner.banners", pk: 2, fields: {banner_name: "Worlds First branded pig iron",…}}
1: {model: "banner.banners", pk: 1, fields: {banner_name: "First branded pig iron",…}}